# UITextField display abnormal

Tags: objective-c, swift, autolayout, uitextfield, uikeyboard

There is a inputBar in my viewController with a textField and two btns, it layout like this :

[image]

The orange part view is the textField, and the two btns I haven't set them backgroundColor.

## When I try to continuously input some words while the content has already exceeded the scope of the textField displayed, the place where places the left switch btn, flashes a part of the textField content which is obscured.

**This kind of situation will only appear in inputing Chinese character**

There is my layout code for the view:

```
    self.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    self.addSubview(switchBtn)
    switchBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    switchBtn.setTitle("switch", for: .normal)
    switchBtn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    switchBtn.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.leading.equalToSuperview()
        make.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(1/8.0)
        make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }

    self.addSubview(sendBtn)
    sendBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    sendBtn.setTitle("send", for: .normal)
    sendBtn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    sendBtn.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.equalTo(switchBtn)
        make.top.bottom.trailing.equalToSuperview()
    }
    self.insertSubview(inputBar, at: 0)
    inputBar.backgroundColor = .orange
    inputBar.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.leading.equalTo(switchBtn.snp.trailing)
        make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(4)
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-4)
        make.trailing.equalTo(sendBtn.snp.leading)
    }
```

I have written the same function code use Objective-C, it occurs the same problem, Could you tell me where my problem is?

Comment: Did you turn clip subviews off?

Comment: @Jerry Thanks, I set the inputBar.clipsToBounds = true, and its works for me. 
But I want to know why it occurs that problem? I haven't ever met the suitation before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the rest of your code, so it's hard to say for sure, but a text field is designed to scroll. When clip subviews is off, the content that is scrolled outside your text field will still be visible.

Comment: Thanks for ur patient answer.